# need active customer list by day wise between selected dates which have start and end date(null also)

Tags: mysql, sql

we need result of no.active customers  between day 1 and day2

the customer will have start and end date some time end date as null i want the active customer between two dates day wise results

```
cust    strdate         end
1     2018-01-01      null
2     2018-01-01    2018-01-03
3     2018-01-02    2018-01-02
4     2018-01-04     null
```

my result for external passed dates 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-04

```
day         count
2018-01-01    2
2018-01-02    3
2018-01-03    2
2018-01-04    2
```

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a calendar table to represent all the dates which you want to see.  For the purpose of your sample data, we can just hard code the dates in a CTE.  With actual data, you would want to generate a date range.  This means that the subquery below aliased as `d` would be replaced with an actual table/view containing the dates whose range you want to include in the query.

```
SELECT
    d.date,
    COUNT(*) AS count
FROM
(
    SELECT '2018-01-01' AS date UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-02' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-03' UNION ALL
    SELECT '2018-01-04'
) d
LEFT JOIN yourTable t
    ON d.date >= t.strdate AND (d.date <= t.enddate OR t.enddate IS NULL)
GROUP BY
    d.date
ORDER BY
    d.date;
```

[image]

### Demo

This answer assumes that if the end date be `NULL`, then it means that the right side of the range is completely open, i.e. all dates would match, provided their start dates are also within range.

Comment: You should replace the CTE with a derived table so the code will work on all the older versions of MySQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff When I answered, I could have sworn that the tag was SQL Server.  Nevertheless, I will update.

Comment: it would be nice if this showed a recursive cte so it works for arbitrarily large date ranges